# Dynamically load feature modules in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

I have defined lazy load module configuration like this:

```
  {
    path: 'pacientes',
    loadChildren: () => import('../pages/cadastro/paciente/paciente-pesquisa/paciente-pesquisa.module').then(m => m.PacientePesquisaModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'pacientes/edit/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('../pages/cadastro/paciente/paciente/paciente.module').then(m => m.PacienteModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'pacientes/create',
    loadChildren: () => import('../pages/cadastro/paciente/paciente/paciente.module').then(m => m.PacienteModule)
  },
```

So I need to define this for at least 10 other routes.
How can I make this without repeating all this code?

I'm looking for something like:

```
addIndex('pacientes', PacienteModule),
addEdit('pacientes', PacienteModule),
addCreate('pacientes', PacienteModule),
```

or other solution.

Comment: All routes under the main route should be ‘normal’ loaded routes inside your lazy loaded module..

Comment: path and module name received from api?